# IndexError: index -9223372036854775808 is out of bounds for dimension 1 with size 2

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, training-data, loss-function

I am trying to train a siamese network with Binary Cross Entropy.

I have the following error in train_epoch:

`y_true_2[range(y_true_2.shape[0]), y_true.long()] = 1`
`IndexError: index -9223372036854775808 is out of bounds for dimension 1 with size 2`

Following is the code snippet for reference:

```
def train_epoch(train_loader, model, loss_fn, optimizer, cuda, log_interval, metrics, logging):
    for metric in metrics:
        metric.reset()

    model.train()
    losses = []
    total_loss = 0

    for batch_idx, ((x0, x1), y) in enumerate(train_loader):

        x0, x1, y_true = x0.cpu(), x1.cpu(), y.cpu()
        gc.collect()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output1, output2 = model(x0, x1)

        '''Distance metric - PairwiseDistance'''
        p_dist = torch.nn.PairwiseDistance(keepdim=True)

        dy = p_dist(output1, output2)
        dy = torch.nan_to_num(dy)
        y_true = torch.nan_to_num(y_true)

        '''2 lines indicated the normalization of dy to 0 and 1 by dividing it with max value'''

        maximum_dy = torch.max(dy)
        maximum_dy = torch.nan_to_num(maximum_dy)
        dy = dy / maximum_dy

        maximum_y_true = torch.max(y_true)
        maximum_y_true = torch.nan_to_num(maximum_y_true)

        y_true = y_true / maximum_y_true

        dy = torch.squeeze(dy, 1)

        'Output tensor of dimension [4,2] and input tensor of dimension [4] to BCE loss function'
        input_dy = torch.empty(dy.size(0), 2)
        input_dy[:, 0] = 1 - dy
        input_dy[:, 1] = dy

        y_true_2 = torch.zeros(dy.size(0), 2)
        y_true_2[range(y_true_2.shape[0]), y_true.long()] = 1

        m = nn.Sigmoid()
        loss = loss_fn(m(input_dy), y_true_2)

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        losses.append(loss.item())
        total_loss += loss.item()

        input_dy_metric = torch.round(input_dy)


        for metric in metrics:
            metric(input_dy_metric, y_true_2)
            metric.total += y_true_2.shape[0]

        if batch_idx % log_interval == 0:
            message = 'Train: [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                batch_idx, len(train_loader),
                100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), np.mean(losses))
            for metric in metrics:
                message += '\t{}: {}'.format(metric.name(), metric.value())

            print(message)
            losses = []

    total_loss /= (batch_idx + 1)
    return total_loss, metrics
```

Please help me with possible solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aside from using a [debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), you could try printing out `y_true_2.shape[0]` and `y_true.long()`. That would at least give you a hint as to which index is producing the `IndexError`.

Comment: Also, have a look at `y_true` before casting to [`Tensor.long`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.long.html)

Comment: Following are the ouputs you suggested to check:   1. print(y_true_2) = tensor([[0., 1.],
        [0., 1.],
        [0., 1.],
        [0., 1.]])   2. print(y_true) = tensor([1., 1., 1., 1.])   3. print(y_true_2.shape[0]) = 4    4. print(range(y_true_2.shape[0])) = range(0,4)   5. print(y_true.long()) = tensor([1, 1, 1, 1])

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace of the error to be sure of the erroneous line

Answer (score 0):

`-9223372036854775808` refers to a `NaN` value.

Try replacing `NaN` values with deterministic values like below before the erroneous line:

```
y_true_2 = torch.where(torch.isnan(y_true_2), torch.zeros_like(y_true_2), y_true_2)
y_true = torch.where(torch.isnan(y_true), torch.zeros_like(y_true), y_true)
```